# $rootScope and passing data from controller to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, rootscope

I'm using angular js and have got a controller looking like this

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp.controllers", []);
myApp.controller("ScheduleCtrl", function($scope, $http, ScheduleService){
    $scope.hours = 4;
    ScheduleService.test();
    ScheduleService.initializeSchedule();
});
```

and a service (in another file) looking like this

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
myApp.factory('ScheduleService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){

    return {
        test : 
            function(){
                alert("Test");
            },
        initializeSchedule : 
            function(){
                alert($rootScope.hours);
            }
    };
});
```

To assure everyone that things are hooked up properly from service to controller, the first call to "test()" inside my controller produces the desired output in the alert box. However, for the next function, which as of now should be alerting "4", is instead alerting "undefined".

How can I use either $rootScope or something else in order to utilize scope variables to my service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject `$rootScope` into your controller and use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope.` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1cgd7ftq/)**

```
myApp.controller("ScheduleCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $http, ScheduleService){
    $rootScope.hours = 4;
    ScheduleService.test();
    ScheduleService.initializeSchedule();
});
```

But in this case you don't need to use `$rootScope.` You can just pass data as parameter into service function.

```
return {
    test : 
        function(){
            alert("Test");
        },
    initializeSchedule : 
        function(hours){
            alert(hours);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to use Angular $rootScope in your controller and view**

To share global properties across app Controllers you can use Angular $rootScope. This is another option to share data.

The preferred way to share common functionality across Controllers is Services, to read or change a global property you can use $rootscope.

All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope, so use  $rootScope wisely.

```
var app = angular.module('mymodule',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$rootScope',
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.showBanner = true;
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope','$rootScope',
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.showBanner = false;
}]);
```

Using $rootScope in a template (Access properties with $root):

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div class="banner" ng-show="$root.showBanner"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $scope is an isolated scope created for your controller.  You need to inject the $rootScope into your controller and modify hours on that if you want it to show up in your service.

See more about scope hierarchies [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ScheduleService', function($scope, $rootScope, ScheduleService) {
  $scope.hours = 4;
  $rootScope.hours = 42;
  ScheduleService.test();
  ScheduleService.initializeSchedule();
}]);
```

service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('ScheduleService', function($rootScope) {
  return {
        test : 
            function(){
                alert("Test");
            },
        initializeSchedule : 
            function(childScopeHours){
                alert($rootScope.hours);
            }
    };
});
```

Working [plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhu0YhgEIb5tqWDnfbuT?p=preview)